# Is this register latency?

Tags: cuda

I am doing some performance CUDA tests on a GTX680 and was wondering whether some one can help me in understanding why I am getting the below performance results. The code that I am running is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


__global__ void test_hardcoded(int rec,int * output)
{

    int a;
    int rec2=rec/2;
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *output=rec;
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *(output+1)=rec2;

    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        a+=i;
    }
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *output=a;   //will never happen but should fool compiler as to not skip the for loop

}
__global__ void test_softcoded(int rec,int * output)
{
    int a;
    int rec2=rec/2; //This should ensure that we are using the a register not constant memory
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *output=rec;
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *(output+1)=rec2;

    for (int i=0;i<=rec2;i++)
    {    __syncthreads();
        a+=i;
    }
    if(threadIdx.x==1000) *output=a;   //will never happen but should fool compiler as to not skip the for loop

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float timestamp;
    cudaEvent_t event_start,event_stop;
    // Initialise
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    cudaEventCreate(&event_start);
    cudaEventCreate(&event_stop);
    cudaEventRecord(event_start, 0);
    dim3 threadsPerBlock;
    dim3 blocks;
    threadsPerBlock.x=32;
    threadsPerBlock.y=32;
    threadsPerBlock.z=1;
    blocks.x=1;
    blocks.y=1000;
    blocks.z=1;

    cudaEventRecord(event_start);
    test_hardcoded<<<blocks,threadsPerBlock,0>>>(10000,NULL);
    cudaEventRecord(event_stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(event_stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&timestamp, event_start, event_stop);
    printf("test_hardcoded() took  %fms \n", timestamp);

    cudaEventRecord(event_start);
    test_softcoded<<<blocks,threadsPerBlock,0>>>(20000,NULL);
    cudaEventRecord(event_stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(event_stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&timestamp, event_start, event_stop);
    printf("test_softcoded() took  %fms \n", timestamp);

}
```

As per code I am running two kernels.. All that they do is to loop and add. The only difference is that is test_softcoded() loop compares to a register, while the test_hardcoded() compares directly to a hardcoded integer.

When I run the above code I get the following results

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 test7.cu
$ ./a.out

test_hardcoded() took  51.353985ms 
test_softcoded() took  99.209694ms
```

the test_hardcoded() function is as twice faster then test-softcoded()!!!!

I understand that in test_softcoded() there is a potential read after write registry dependency but my awareness is that the registry latency is completely hidden for high occupancy and it should be very high), so I am wondering what might be the problem and what to do as to enhance performance for test_softcoded().

Comment: Can you post the PTX generated by your compiler for both cases? This may be the result of loop unrolling, as pointed out by user1695033, or the use of immediate operands.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this hard coded value, compiler can do some optimizations, like loop unrolling, which may increase the performance by some amount. that may be the reason.

You can check it by adding some unrolling to for loop in "test_softcoded" like 
Adding code like '#pragma unroll 5000' before 'for (int i=0;i<=rec2;i++)' and running it will solve your doubt.